# MatLab fmin function

Tags: function, matlab, fminsearch

I have an .m file in matlab named `PowerMinimiser` and two functions in it

```
function PowerMinimiser
    PowerOut = fmin(minFunction,0,100);
    display(PowerOut)
end
```

and

```
function PowerOut = minFunction(varargin)
    RunMode = 2;
    ThresholdValue = 10;
    if nargin > 0
        ThresholdValue  = varargin{1};
    end
    %Receive PowerOut value from .main file and pass in ThresholdValue and
    %RunMode values:
    [PowerOut] = main(ThresholdValue,RunMode);
end
```

Now what I would like to do is use the matlab `fmin` function so that I can find a value for the variable `ThresholdValue` which will give the lowest value possible for the variable `PowerOut`. The value for `ThresholdValue` is a number between 1 and 100, and is passed into a function in the `main.m` where a number of calculations are done and then a value for `PowerOut` is outputted.

Using the `minFunction` function I am able to receive and pass the variable fine, using the line

```
     [PowerOut] = main(ThresholdValue,RunMode);
```

but I am not sure how to use the `fmin` function to get the value of `ThresholdValue` that gives the lowest value for `PowerOut`. I would like the `ThresholdValue` value to be shown once the `fmin` has done the necessary calculations. How can I do this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use function [`fminbnd`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fminbnd.html), which replaced [`fmin`](http://www.weizmann.ac.il/matlab/techdoc/ref/fmin.html) function in newer versions of Matlab. To pass function as an argument to `fminbnd` use `@` in front of the function name, like this:

```
PowerOut = fmin( @minFunction, 0, 100 );
```